why Python built-in str join() method is not faster than simple +=?
binary_str= np.random.randint(2,size=1000000,dtype='int')

method 1:
binary_str=''.join(binary_str.astype(str))

method 2:
s=''
for c in binary_str:
    s+=str(c)

I read many articles saying that method 1 is supposed to be much faster since it concatenate the whole string once. By contrast method 2 has to allocate memory and copy for each step, which leads to time complexity of O(n^2).
But when I measure the time consumed by either time.time or timeit, the output of the two methods are nearly the same, and method 1 even consumed more time. Why? Python version 3.10.4.
It is caused by str method and iterating through numpy. When using astype(str) at the beginning and use .tolist(), the performance difference is huge.

The commonly used CPython implementation features an optimization for this: https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/string-concat.html It is the only Python implementation I know of that does this, so this is not portable to IronPython, etc.

Because you are actually measuring the string conversion. It takes more than 10 times as long as the join.

Python - Creating a string through large numbers of String Concatenation - What method should be used? - and the answer is still "".join(), regardless of apparent better results with +=.

Slower string concatenation in CPython 3.11

@Homer512 This probably is not even true for recent CPython implementations - 3.11 and up do not use that optimisation. See above issue.

@matszwecja Interesting. However, if I read the bug report correctly, the optimization still exists. It is just limited to local variables inside a function

@matszwecja if this gets closed as a dupe I'll delete my answer

JonSG's answer is correct
@matszwecja this question is of different context in that the time spent mostly in transforming into str

Though I'm using python 3.12, I'm convinced that join() is faster and that you are not measuring apples to apples as they say. Let's try to do that by doing the casting the same way before passing the result to either strategy:

import timeit

setup = """
import numpy
binary_str= numpy.random.randint(2, size=1_000_000, dtype='int').astype(str).tolist()

def test_join(text):
    return "".join(text)

def test_concat(text):
    foo = ""
    for c in text:
        foo += c
    return foo
"""
test_runs = 100

print("test_join", timeit.timeit("test_join(binary_str)", setup=setup, number=test_runs))
print("test_concat", timeit.timeit("test_concat(binary_str)", setup=setup, number=test_runs))

that gives me a result like:
test_join 0.7373489998281002
test_concat 10.110920300008729

Even if I don't cast the array to a list and just use it:

import timeit

setup = """
import numpy
binary_str= numpy.random.randint(2, size=1_000_000, dtype='int').astype(str)

def test_join(text):
    return "".join(text)

def test_concat(text):
    foo = ""
    for c in text:
        foo += c
    return foo
"""
test_runs = 1

print("test_join", timeit.timeit("test_join(binary_str)", setup=setup, number=test_runs))
print("test_concat", timeit.timeit("test_concat(binary_str)", setup=setup, number=test_runs))

I still get a result like:
test_join 0.26619710004888475
test_concat 17.36303890007548

So, if you are looking at concatenating a list or array of characters into a larger string, join() is way faster.
